# What package is causing Atom to reformat my Python files on-save?

Tags: python, atom-editor, formatter

Every time I save a [Python](https://www.python.org/) file on my [Atom](https://atom.io/) text editor, it gets automatically reformatted.

Usually this is a good thing, but sometimes it's extremely frustrating, in certain situations where the formatter makes bad choices.

What package is causing this behavior and how can I disable it?

Comment: It seems like atom-ide-ui is causing this trouble.

Comment: Note that linting and formatting are totally different things: linting just finds problems, it doesn't change your code. And FWIW, [Black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is a commonly used Python formatter.

Comment: @wjandrea thank you for the clarification.  I will update the title to say "reformat" instead of "lint".

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that [`atom-ide-ui`](https://github.atom.io/packages/atom-ide-ui) was indeed the culprit.  Note that the [repo](https://github.com/facebookarchive/atom-ide-ui) for that project is now archived.